# Catch undefined class methods in PHP

Tags: php

Let's say I have a class `HTMLElement` where I want to be able to call:

`$element->href("http://www.google.com")`

and catch the undefined method dynamically. For example:

```
class HTMLElement{

    public function __catch($method, $args){
        $this->attribute[$method] = $args[0];
    }

}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is the `__call` method

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

From the site:

`public mixed __call ( string $name , array $arguments )`

__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

In your example, `$name` would be "href" and `$arguments` would be an array of whatever you pass `["http://www.google.com"]`